# MotionLayout not animating smoothly

Tags: android, android-motionlayout

I have a `Fragment` whose layout consists of a `MotionLayout` that has two children.  One child is a horizontal `RecyclerView` and the other child is a `FrameLayout`.  They are stacked vertically.

```
MotionLayout
--RecyclerView (horizontal)
--FrameLayout
```

Inside the `FrameLayout` is a `ViewPager` -- and each page is a `Fragment` with a vertical `RecyclerView`.  I want the scrolling of this vertical `RecyclerView` to collapse/expand the `FrameLayout` over the horizontal `RecyclerView` just like a `CollapsingToolbarLayout` would.

It's pretty easy to get this "working" with the following scene:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MotionScene xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <Transition
        app:constraintSetEnd="@+id/collapsed"
        app:constraintSetStart="@+id/expanded">

        <OnSwipe
            app:dragDirection="dragDown"
            app:onTouchUp="autoComplete"
            app:touchAnchorId="@+id/vertical_recycler_view"
            app:touchAnchorSide="top" />

    </Transition>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/expanded">

        <Constraint
            android:id="@id/my_framelayout"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/horizontal_recycler_view" />

    </ConstraintSet>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/collapsed">

        <Constraint
            android:id="@id/my_framelayout"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </ConstraintSet>

</MotionScene>
```

This "works."  The `FrameLayout` "collapses" over the horizontal `RecyclerView` as expected.

My issue is that the animation does not happen smoothly (over time).  The `FrameLayout` snaps collapsed/expanded immediately.

Could anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: Did you found a solution ?

Comment: Same issue here...

Answer (score 1):

The `snaps collapsed/expanded` is the intended behaviour for `app:onTouchUp="autoComplete"`.

If you want the collapsing animation to follow your scrolling, try change the `app:onTouchUp="autoComplete"` to `app:onTouchUp="stop"`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `app:touchAnchorSide` to bottom

Answer (score 0):

Just change **`app:dragDirection="dragDown"`** into `app:dragDirection="dragUp"`